# Polynom Package Multiplication

Tags: polynomials

Ok! So...was really pleased when I discovered that `polynom` will just do polynomial long division for me like it's no big deal. But...is there a function for multiplying polynomials? I seem to have found something called `\polymul` in the manual, but...there isn't any detail about how to use it (and I keep getting errors when trying to multiply simple polynomials): http://cs.brown.edu/about/system/managed/latex/doc/polynom.pdf

Any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Not sure why someone would vote this down...

Comment: Hi, welcome. I didn't downvote, but it could be because you haven't shown what you tried.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please show us the code that you have tried and the precise error messages. Otherwise it is hard to say what's going wrong. For me the package `polynom` works when I try the code in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the manual, you could do something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polynom}
\begin{document}
% the next two lines are just to save the two polynoms we want to multiply to \PolynomA and \PolynomB
\polyadd\PolynomA{x-1}{0} % adding zero: trick mentioned in the manual
\polyadd\PolynomB{x^2+2}{0}%
% multiply A and B, save to \SomePolynom
\polymul\SomePolynom\PolynomA\PolynomB
\begin{equation}
(\polyprint\PolynomA)(\polyprint\PolynomB)=\polyprint\SomePolynom
\end{equation}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

In general, you do `\polymul\SomeMacronameYouDecideYourself{<first polynom>}{<second polynom>}`. To get useful output, you need to use `\polyprint\SomeMacronameYouDecideYourself`.

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks! I couldn't find documentation on polymul...or maybe I just wasn't reading carefully enough. Anyway I ended up putting my things into a polynomial multiplier widget on Wolfram, but I still wanted to know this for the future. Just finished special cases and now moving on to a general case of a research problem! To the abstract notation!

Comment: @TannerStrunk I didn't actually look at your link before, but it leads to an older version of the manual. Type `texdoc polynom` in a terminal on your computer, or visit http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/polynom/polynom.pdf for the latest version. Then have a look at section 4.6 (*Low-level commands*), which is where I got the info for this answer.